# How to export json data to csv or txt file

Tags: python, html, flask

I'm new graduated and newbie in python.Now I'm create basic web application with flask.[image: This's my Web application.]
[image: This's my Result.]

And this's my code.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, send_file
import smtplib
from email.mime.image import MIMEImage
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.header import Header
import csv
from datetime import datetime
from io import StringIO
from werkzeug.wrappers import Response
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/')
def index():
   return render_template('index.html')
@app.route('/save',methods = ['POST'])
def save():
   x = dict(request.form.items())
   return "Success %s"%(x)
app.run()
```

This's my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Bootstrap Example</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
<h2>ใบฟอร์ม_โอนเงิน_ทดสอบ_E-mail_Approvel_Project</h2>
</div>
<form id="contact-form" action="/save", method="POST">
    <p>ชื่อ - สกุล:<input type = "text" name = "save1" /></p>
    <p>วันที่:<input type = "date" name = "save2" /></p>
    <p>เลขที่เอกสาร:<input type = "text" name = "save3" /></p>
    <p>รายละเอียด:<input type = "text" name = "save4" /></p>
    <p>จำนวนเงิน:<input type = "text" name = "save5" /></p>

    <p><input type = "submit" value = "submit" /></p>
   </form>
    </div>

    </body>
   </html>
```

Now : 
1.I need export my result to csv or txt files.
Please tell me how to get it.Apologize for mistake and bad English skill.

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research?

Comment: @Dear AMC My issue is how to export my result to txt or csv files.I tried to find tutorial, youtube lesson and another research. I am very sorry that makes you do not feel good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import csv

with open('file.csv', mode='w') as csv_file:
fieldnames = ['header1', 'header2', 'header3']
     writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames=fieldnames)

     writer.writeheader()
     writer.writerow({'name': 'John Smith', 'dept': 'Accounting','birth_month': 'November'})
```

This would be a sample code that you can put in one of your functions. You would be writing to a csv file called "file.csv"